# strategy for button that fires Http Request

Tags: java, android, intentservice

I have a Like and Dislike `Button` that fire an `IntentService` to update the status of the resource on the Server if the user like or dislike that particular resource . 
no to avoid sending too much request to server by clicking too much on any button . what should i do ?

What i thought about is to update the resource locally in (database ) and append an intent in a queue to  fire the service after 150 millisecond . and if there a matching intent i will remove it from queue . is there anything else to do ???

Comment: you can deactivate the button until the resource has actually been updated on the server.

Comment: You could make your button unavaible for something like 1 sec after the user presses it. It may not be the best solution, so I'm just commenting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just save a preference with last event timestamp in a SharedPreferences object. If not enough time passed since you sent the last event don't try to do another call. The method where you press the button would do the following:

- get the last event sent timestamp from SharedPreferences
- if not enough time passed do nothing
- otherwise make the call and update the timestamp in SharedPreferences